# Laravel Factory - How to make meaningful dummy data with a Factory

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I want to make gender, age, and nationality of Korea and Japan, but I don't know what to do.

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $gender = $faker->randomElement(['men', 'women']);
    $address = $faker->randomElement(['seoul', 'fucuoka', 'tokyo']);
    $country = $faker->randomElement(['korea', 'japan']);
    $age = rand(3, 100);

    return [
        'name'              => $faker->name,
        'email'             => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password'          => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret,
        'country'           => $country,
        'address'           => $address,
        'age'               => $age,
        'gender'            => $gender,
        'remember_token'    => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about setting the locale to Korean via Laravel? Then Faker will produce a Korean address etc.

Add this to your app.php file in the config folder:

```
'faker_locale' => 'ko_KR',
```

All locales available can be found here:

https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/locales/ko_KR.html

Comment: How do I call it?

Comment: As i have described it, it would be set globaly and working for all factories in your project.

Comment: Is that what you want? Then you simply need to copy the line into config/app.php and its ready to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

add this **line(key)** in your `config/app.php` file

```
'faker_locale' => 'ko_KR',
```

and run `config:cache` command

```
 php artisan config:cache
```

other wise create object like that if don't want to globally

```
 Faker\Factory::create('ko_KR')
```

and in your should be like that addd

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker\Factory::create('ko_KR') $faker)
```

Comment: Why cache a config on local development?